# Display specific records from table using joins mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following table.

```
   ID SampleID SampleState Date
1   A1   First 1/10/2013
2   A1   Second 1/11/2013
3   A1   Last   1/12/2013
4   A2   First  1/10/2013
5   A2   Closed 1/11/2013
6   A3   First  1/10/2012
7   A3   Second 1/10/2012
```

I have to pull out the rows using the following rule.

```
a.) Display the lowest date of each SampleID provided the date is more than 10 days from current day
b.) Display the latest state of each SampleID.
c.) Do not display the SampleID if any of the state of the SampleID is Closed
```

For example,
For this table, the output should be

```
    SampleID SampleState Date
     A1   Last   1/10/2013
     A3   Second 1/10/2012
```

My query doesn't display all the results.

```
SELECT  a.SampleID,a.SampleState,b.date
FROM    ListOfStates 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ID,SampleID, Max(ID) Max_ID, SampleState
            FROM    ListOfStates 
            GROUP   BY SampleID
        ) a 
    on a.Max_ID = ListOfStates.ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ID,SampleID, Min(ID) min_ID, date
            FROM    ListOfStates 
            GROUP   BY SampleID
        ) b
on b.min_ID = ListOfStates.ID

where              

 b.Date  < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
and a.SampleState !='Closed'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following takes your conditions and puts them into a single query:

```
select SampleId,
       min(case when t.Date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) then date end) as MinDate,
       max(case when t.date = tsum.maxDate then state end) as MostRecentState
from t join
     (select SampleId, max(date) as maxDate
      from t
      group by SampleId
     ) tsum
     on t.SampleId = tsum.SampleId
group by SampleId
having max(case when state = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 and
       min(date) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

I think the key is the conditional aggregations.  You can aggregate things using the `case` statement in the `select` clause, rather than filtering using `where` clause (or `having` clause).

Comment: Thanks for showing me another way to do this? I'll try this. I still don't understand. Why isn't filtering using where or having clause effective?

Comment: I get NULLS in lots of dates fields when I run this query. my original dates aren't nulls

Comment: @Ankur . . . There are NULLs in the MinDate because of condition (a).  Some sampleids simply have no dates more than 10 day sold.  The latest state should not be NULL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. SampleID's do have dates that are more than 10 days old. They aren't being displayed in the query..

Comment: I do not want to display those sampleID whose min date is not more than 10 days from now..